# React Hooks - Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm pretty new to both javascript and react hooks and I keep getting a 'Too many re-renders' error with the following code

```
const [showReminder, setShowReminder] = useState(
    lastDismissedDate.diff(overrideDate, 'days') >= 0,
  );

  if (latestIndexScore && !hasCompletedIndexRecently(latestIndexScore.date)) {
    setShowReminder(true);
  }
```

Is there any way I can combine the two statements into one. Something like

```
const [showReminder, setShowReminder] = useState(
    latestIndexScore && !hasCompletedIndexRecently(latestIndexScore.date) || lastDismissedDate.diff(overrideDate, 'days') >= 0,
  );
```

Comment: why using state if it can just be derived from other variables? like `const showReminder = latestIndexScore && !hasCompletedIndexRecently(latestIndexScore.date) || lastDismissedDate.diff(overrideDate, 'days') >= 0` or something like that

Comment: You calling setShowReminder(true) on every render, check your conditions.

Comment: @RamKrish2079 I'm using state because when a button of the reminder is clicked the reminder should not show using setShowReminder(false);

Comment: then your second approach should work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
          if (latestIndexScore && !hasCompletedIndexRecently(latestIndexScore.date)) 
          {
            setShowReminder(true);
          }
```

In the above code, the condition is true
then the setShowReminder will run or will change its state
in react if the state changes it will render again
so the codes will run again (the if statement) then the setShowReminder will run again and it will change the state again .... that cause Too many re-renders

try to use useEffect hooks and pass an array as an second argument to useEffect like this

```
            const [showReminder, setShowReminder] = useState(false);

            useEffect(() => {
               setShowReminder(!showReminder);
            }, [toggle]); // Only re-run the effect if toggle changes
```